# Using javascript to hide div in UIWebView

Tags: javascript, html, uiwebview, hide

i am attempting to use java script to hide a few divs from a webpage, however it doesn't seem to work, can anyone help me, heres my code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

NSString *urlAddress = @"http://tvmdn.org/";

//Create a URL object.
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];

//URL Requst Object
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

//Load the request in the UIWebView.
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];

[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"var script = document.createElement('script');"  

 "script.type = 'text/javascript';"  

 "script.text = \"function hideID(idName) { "  

 "var id = document.getElementById(idName);"  

 "id.style.display = 'none';"

 "}\";" 

 "document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);"];  

[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"hideID('headerbar');"];  

}
```

Thanks, Sami.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't need to inject the javascript like that (by creating the script element dynamically).  You should just be able to do it like this:

Make your class a `UIWebViewDelegate` (see: [Apple Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006951)) and just implement the javascript like this:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webview{
    NSString *js = @"var element = document.getElementById('headerbar');  element.style.dislay = 'none';";
    NSString *res = [webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:js];
   [super webViewDidFinishLoad:webview];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Brendan's answer is correct, but here is a lean twist to the above

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webview{

    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"(\".classIdToHide\").hide();"];
}
```